# Spectrum of a positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

We know that if $A$ is a self-adjoint unbounded  operator on a Hilbert space $(H;\left<.,.\right>)$ then $\sigma(A) \subset \mathbb R$. Now, how it can be shown that if $A$ is more positive i.e. $\left<Au,u\right> \geq 0$, then $\sigma(A) \subset \mathbb [0,+\infty[$ ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that $\overline{\mathrm{ran}(A-\lambda)}=\ker(A-\lambda)^\perp$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, it suffices to show that $\ker(A-\lambda)=\{0\}$ and that $\mathrm{ran}(A-\lambda)$ is closed.

Let $\lambda<0$. We have
$$
\|(A-\lambda)u\|\|u\|\geq\langle (A-\lambda) u,u\rangle\geq -\lambda\|u\|^2
$$
for all $u\in D(A)$.

Thus, $\ker(A-\lambda)=0$ and $A-\lambda$ is invertible as operator from $D(A)$ to $\mathrm{ran}(A-\lambda)$. It follows that $\mathrm{ran}(A-\lambda)$ is complete, hence closed.

Comment: @ MaoWao: Why $\overline{\mathrm{ran}(A-\lambda)}=\ker(A-\lambda)^\perp=\{0\} $ ? because, if $A-\lambda$ is injective for $\lambda<0$ then $\ker(A-\lambda)=\{0\}$.

Comment: @Z.Alfata: it is clearly a typo, it should say $H$ where it say $\{0\}$.